# Exporting mysql db(data with numbers) to csv

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to write a coed where i have to export the contents of my database into a csv file

the exporting already works however my exported csv is having problems with numbers

for example my sql database looks like this

```
telephone number
+639063073755
```

however in the exported csv the data from the telephone number becomes like this

```
telephone number
6.39063E+11
```

the telephone number becomes an exponent

is there a way to fix this

here is my code

```
$sql = DB::query("SELECT * FROM table 1 order by id ASC");
$col2 = DB::query("SELECT * FROM table2 order by col_id ASC");
$rp_name = DB::queryOneField('rp_name',"SELECT * FROM report_presets where rp_id=%i",$_GET['rp_id']);
$rp_name = str_replace(" ","",$rp_name);


$line1 .= "Telephone Number";


foreach($sql as $row){
$line2 .=

str_replace(",","",$row[mobile_no]). ","

."\n";
    }

$data="$line1\n$line2\n";

header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$rp_name.".csv"); 
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
print "$header\n$data";
```

thanks

Comment: Does it really show `6.39063E+11` in the raw CSV content (view in a plain text editor)? or is your software changing it to that (ie Excel).

Comment: im using excel. i guess the problem lies with excel thanks for the answer

Comment: concert the number into string before sending to CSV file and convert back to long before retrieving

Answer (score 2):

If you are using excel to view the csv this problem may occur. 
Thats not the problem of your code.
try formatting the column as number

Comment: i guess excel is the one  that automatically converts it into an exponent. now my only worry is if someone who does not know how to use excel uses the code

Comment: The solution is to force excel to treat the number as a string itself and not a number. For that put a $ or any alphabet or something like that at the end.

Comment: Well I guess putting two or more tabs at the end will do.

Comment: So that your display won't be affected

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in how Excel handles the contents of the CSV. Follow [these instructions](http://risingline.com/use-excel-read-csv-without-reformatting.php) in order to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because of  excel cell width . can u add any character before the telephone number like " call:989898989898". Then there wont be problem.

Comment: this method worked but it just doesnt feel right when there is a word right next to it. thanks for the answer